# C# NetworkAvailibilityChanged doesn't trigger on disconnect

Tags: c#, winforms

My goal is to detect when the Ethernet cable gets disconnected I am attempting to use `NetworkChange` class but the event `NetworkAvailibilityChanged` does not trigger when I unplug Ethernet cable. `NetworkAddressChanged` does get triggered in about 8 seconds but `NetworkAvailibilityChanged` never does, is there is anything am I am missing?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            NetworkChange.NetworkAvailabilityChanged += new NetworkAvailabilityChangedEventHandler(NetworkChange_NetworkAvailabilityChanged);
            NetworkChange.NetworkAddressChanged += new NetworkAddressChangedEventHandler(NetworkChange_NetworkAddressChanged);
        }

        void NetworkChange_NetworkAvailabilityChanged(object sender, NetworkAvailabilityEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("NetworkChange_NetworkAvailabilityChanged");
        }

        void NetworkChange_NetworkAddressChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("NetworkChange_NetworkAddressChanged");
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 2):

NetworkAvailabilityChanged is based on NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable(), which sates:

> A network connection is considered to be available if any network interface is marked "up" and is not a loopback or tunnel interface.

So if there are multiple NICs, NetworkAddressChanged won't fire when a cable is unplugged if there is a second NIC (cabled or wireless) that meets those criteria.

Comment: it appears that network for virtual machine count as well, I had a VirtualBox Host-Only Network which I have to disable to let `NetworkAvailabilityChanged` work.